# How to not have pgdb add quotes

Tags: python, postgresql, pygresql, pgdb

I'm doing an SQL insterface, and I'm having a problem with string formatting. What I want to do is an SQL `INSERT INTO table_name` statement. When I do it now, using parameterized instertion, I get unwanted quotes around my table name. This is the code:

```
    query = "INSERT INTO %(table)s VALUES %(vals)s;"

    self.cur.execute(query, params)
```

What happens is this:

```
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "'books'"
LINE 1: INSERT INTO 'books' VALUES 'hej, hej, hej, hej';
```

As you can see, there are quotation marks around books, causing a syntax error.

I have tried to find info on this but with no luck. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot use execute parameters as table names or column names. They are only allowed for values.

You have to format the SQL-statement first:

```
query = "INSERT INTO {} VALUES ({})".format(table_name, ','.join(['%s']*number_of_columns))
self.cur.execute(query, params)
```

Or better, use a package, that already provide some database-abstraction, like SQLAlchemy.